# Error executing child request for handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, child-actions

I use a child action in Home Controller  like this:

```
  [OutputCache(Duration=30)]
    public ActionResult ChildAction()
    {
        Response.Write("Date Time is="+DateTime.Now);
        return View();
    }

Home.cshtml
<h2>About</h2>
<p>
   @Html.Action("ChildAction")  
</p>
```

but after run my asp.net mvc3.0 Project i get an error :

The view 'ChildAction' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

```
~/Views/Home/ChildAction.aspx
~/Views/Home/ChildAction.ascx
~/Views/Shared/ChildAction.aspx
~/Views/Shared/ChildAction.ascx
~/Views/Home/ChildAction.cshtml
~/Views/Home/ChildAction.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/ChildAction.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/ChildAction.vbhtml
```

please help me how can i solve it
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a view named "ChildAction", or in action you should return view as
`return View("ViewName");` In summary, view name should be same as action name, not controller name as you did(You named view as "Home").